# Opposite of ずにはいられない

Tags: grammar

What is the opposite of "ずにはいられない "?
I would like to write the following sentence patterns:

憂鬱な日には、お酒を飲まずにはいられないと思う人がいる。
私は、彼ら達とは逆に、憂鬱な日だからと言って、お酒を飲むのが必要ということにはならないと思います。

Is there a more elegant expression than the "お酒を飲むのが必要ということにはならない"?

Answer (score 5):

How about...

「～ずにいられる・～ないでいられる」「～ずにすませられる・～ないですませられる」 or 「～なくても平気・大丈夫」

> 私は彼らとは違い、憂鬱な日でもお酒は飲まずにいられると思います。
>   私は彼らと違って、憂鬱な日でもお酒は飲まなくても平気だと思います。